# Eclipse CDT C/C++ code completion problem in NDK / Java project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android (Java) project that includes some native C/C++ code and I need it to be able to code complete on various C classes & functions. However the option to include where the (full) source is from does not seem to be available in the Android (Java) project.

Does anyone know of a way to either:
1) Trick Eclipse into including the necessary Project Properties panel item (side panel)?
2) Include the files manually through the use of some form of configuration file?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two basic ways to setup a NDK builder in Eclipse:

1. Creating a custom builder - a bit easier in setup and more portable but does not provide C++ auto-completion and you can not navigate to source by double-clicking in the error console. (This seems to be your case.)
2. CDT-based builder - results in less portable configuration but provides all IDE features for JNI code.

Here is a good-looking tutorial for the CDT configuration: 
http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

To enable the code completion for external sources (and for standard Android headers) you need to open "Project properties" > "C/C++ general" > "Paths and symbols" and add your include paths to the list:

[image]

`NDKROOT` - an environment variable containing path to my NDK

Comment: The project includes JNI C++ code that is built automatically using a builder. But the C/C++ general option is not available in the project properties.

Comment: This means that you have not converted your project to the C/C++ project and CDT plugin does not really work for your JNI code. I'll try to see if I have a link to a CDT tutorial.

Comment: To enable the C/C++ General panel in Eclipse add the <nature>org.eclispe.cdt.cnature</nature> within the <natures> block of your .project file. This for some reason does not enable Paths and Symbols within the panel though.

Comment: Actually, you can convert without having to modify a hidden file - go to New -> Other... -> C/C++ -> Convert to a C/C++ Project. This will take care of it. Mighty intuitive to find a project converter under "New".