# Eclipse marks c++ files as incorrect and doesn't let to compile

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk

As of yesterday I have a very annoying problem:

- I am using sequoyah
- If I import the project without opening any c++ files, I can compile with no problems, but just as I open any of them, almost all of it gets marked by red curly underline.
- Error is as if I had no includes of jni.h, GLES2/gl2.h, string and many more including my own headers. Those errors won't let me compile.
- C++ plugins are installed.

The biggest problem is, that as long as I don't touch jni folder Eclipse compiles them into working apk. What might be causing it and how could I fix it?

EDIT: I get a few errors and warnings:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.
Invalid project path: Include path not found (D:\usr\include).
Invalid project path: Include path not found (D:\usr\lib\gcc\i686-pc-cygwin\4.5.3\include\c++).
```

EDIT2: I can compile if I use command line and then press compile on the project who doesn't have sequoyah set up. Everything would be fine except for the fact that I don't know what IDE to use on those cpp files if eclipse doesn't work...

P. S. Those of you who compile native code via command line, what editor do you use to write code itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few of the many problems were:

- empty includes under Properties->C/C++ general->Paths and symbols (needed to add C:\android-ndk-r8\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include and many other folder with header files)
- also in Properties->C/C++ Build section Behaviour removed clean option and left Build field empty.
- In Builders section of the Properties removed cdt and make file options. So now I only edit file in eclipse and compile vie cmd.

Pages that helped:

[mhandroid.wordpress.com](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/)

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166441/eclipse-cdt-c-c-code-completion-problem-in-ndk-java-project)